# Merge - Orcle error

Tags: oracle, merge

While executing below code, getting  error **"Missing ON keyword"**  but  I have already written ON clause. Please assist on cause.

```
merge into emp_temp s

using (select p.employee_id, p.salary, p.last_name,p.email, p.Hire_date, 
p.job_id from employees p
minus 
   select s.employee_id, s.salary, s.last_name,s.email, s.Hire_date, 
s.job_id from emp_temp s    
) EMPLOYEES p

ON (s.employee_id = p.employee_id)

when matched then
 update set s.salary = p.salary

when not matched then
insert 
(s.employee_id , s.salary,s.last_name,s.email,s.Hire_date, s.job_id) 
values
    (p.employee_id, p.salary, p.last_name,p.email, p.Hire_date, p.job_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coming from this line:

```
) EMPLOYEES p
```

You're setting the using clause's alias as `EMPLOYEE`, but that you're trying to re-alias *that* as just `p`. The error doesn't mean that you don't have an `ON` clause at all, just that it isn't where the parser is expecting to see it.

Since you refer to `p` later, you just want that single alias:

```
...
minus 
   select s.employee_id, s.salary, s.last_name,s.email, s.Hire_date, 
s.job_id from emp_temp s    
) p

ON (s.employee_id = p.employee_id)
...
```